# Github/Actions comment on PR from repository_dispatch

Tags: github-actions

Is there a way to find a PR (based on it's branch name) and post a comment to it;  when triggered from a repository_dispatch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming from your question that you are sending the `ref` of the pull request to the `repository_dispatch` event. I don't know how you are doing that, but here is one way for reference.

```
      - name: Repository Dispatch
        uses: peter-evans/repository-dispatch@v1
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.REPO_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
          repository: username/my-repo
          event-type: my-event
          client-payload: '{"ref": "${{ github.ref }}"}'
```

That makes the `ref` available at `github.event.client_payload.ref` in the `repository_dispatch` event context.

```
on: repository_dispatch
jobs:
  commentOnPr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v2
        id: get-pr-number
        with:
          script: |
            const {data: pulls} = await github.pulls.list({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              state: 'open',
              head: '${{ github.event.client_payload.ref }}'
            })
            return pulls[0].number
          result-encoding: string

      - name: Create comment
        uses: peter-evans/create-or-update-comment@v1
        with:
          issue-number: ${{ steps.get-pr-number.outputs.result }}
          body: |
            This is a multi-line test comment
            - With GitHub **Markdown** :sparkles:
            - Created by [create-or-update-comment][1]

            [1]: https://github.com/peter-evans/create-or-update-comment
          reactions: '+1'
```